# How to bind TextBox text to RadListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radlistbox

I have two `RadListBoxes`, i.e `radListBoxSource` and `RadListBoxDestination`.

Here I am binding `radListBoxSource` items with `DataSource` and transfer to `RadListBoxDestination`.

Now I want to add some text from `TextBox` to `RadListBoxDestination` which data is not in `radListBoxSource`.

For this I added `TextBox` and `Button`.
Please tell me how to bind `TextBox` data and `radListBoxSource` data to `RadListBoxDestination`.

.aspx:

```
<telerik:RadListBox runat="server" ID="radListBoxSource" Height="350px" Width="250px"
                    EnableDragAndDrop="true" TransferMode="Move" SelectionMode="Multiple" AllowTransfer="true"
                    TransferToID="RadListBoxDestination" AutoPostBackOnTransfer="true" DataSortField="CandidateColumn"
                    DataKeyField="ColumnID" AllowReorder="true">
    <EmptyMessageTemplate>
        No columns exist
    </EmptyMessageTemplate>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">
                    Candidate Columns
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="width: 100%;">
            <%# Eval("CandidateColumn") %>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListBox>
<telerik:RadListBox ID="RadListBoxDestination" Height="350px" Width="250px" runat="server"
                    SelectionMode="Multiple" EnableDragAndDrop="true" AllowReorder="true">
    <EmptyMessageTemplate>
        No columns exist
    </EmptyMessageTemplate>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">
                    Candidate Columns
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="width: 100%;">
            <%# Eval("CandidateColumn") %>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListBox>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" Text="Enter Custom Field Name" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFieldName" runat="server" Width="175px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" CssClass="form_btn_txt" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

.cs:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadListBoxItem test1 = new RadListBoxItem("item 1");
    test1.Text = txtFieldName.Text.Trim();
    RadListBoxDestination.Items.Insert(test1.Clone());              
}
```

And I am binding radListBoxSource  as follows:

```
private void FillComboData()
{
    BizCandidate bizCandidates = new BizCandidate();
    DataSet dsCandidates = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        dsCandidates = bizCandidates.GetCandidateColumns();

        if (dsCandidates != null && dsCandidates.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dsCandidates.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                radListBoxSource.DataSource = dsCandidates.Tables[0];
                radListBoxSource.DataValueField = "ColumnID";
                radListBoxSource.DataTextField = "CandidateColumn";
                radListBoxSource.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: If you remove the ItemTemplate from RadListBoxDestination, it will probably work. But it looks like you are mixing up things. Eval() is used when you have some kind of data source bound to your list box. How do you set the default values for the two list boxes, in the code behind? Also, you don't need the call to .Clone(). You are just creating a clone of a newly created object.

Comment: Here i am moving items from radListBoxSource to RadListBoxDestination.

Comment: Ok, I have written an answer.

Comment: What i have written code in btnAdd_Click event that is correct or not.Please tell me.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. But you should remove the .Clone()-call. It doesn't do anything. Just makes a copy of the newly created object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the itemTemplate from the RadListBoxDestination, as you are not using a data source for this list box:

```
<telerik:RadListBox ID="RadListBoxDestination" Height="350px" Width="250px" runat="server"
                    SelectionMode="Multiple" EnableDragAndDrop="true" AllowReorder="true">
    <EmptyMessageTemplate>
        No columns exist
    </EmptyMessageTemplate>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">
                    Candidate Columns
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
</telerik:RadListBox>
```